# Thymeleaf th:field to String variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My target is to create a html file containings a form for the user, with different types of input (int, String, etc.). I am using SpringBoot, Thymeleaf, Lombok and J8. So I have a Java class:

```java
    @ToString
    @Getter
    public class MyClass {
        private int myValue;
        private String myStringValue;
    }
```

Furthermore i have a html-file with the following form:

```xml
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/path/route}" th:object="${myObject}" method="post">
        <div>
            <label>MyValue:</label> 
            <input type="text" min="0" max="10" th:field="*{myValue}" />
        </div>
        
        <div>
            <label>MyStringValue:</label> 
            <input type="text" min-length="1" max-length="10" th:field="*{myStringValue}" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Post"/> 
        </div>          
    </form>
```

and a Controller class:

```java
    @PostMapping("/path/route")
    public String mymethod(@ModelAttribute MyClass myObject) {
        
        try {
            log.info("Input: {}", myObject.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Failed {}", e);
        }
        return "template";
    }
```

Summary: I have a form containing a value, which should be mapped to a numerical variable (myValue) and a value, which should be mapped to a String-object (MyStringValue)

Can somebody explain me, why the numerical mapping works, and the variable myStringValue is always null?

Thanks a lot, best regards
Alex

Comment: I think you need to add @Setter as well on the MyClass otherwise it will never be able to set value. Integer might be using default 0.

Comment: Without a setter neither will work and it only appears to work.

Comment: Thanks guys. My fault.